# BeautifulSoup checking if an element has a specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
for containerElement in container:
    brandingElement = containerElement.find("div", class_="item-branding")
    titleElement=containerElement.find("a", class_="item-title")
    rating = brandingElement.find("i", {"class":"rating"})["aria-label"]
    priceElement = containerElement.find("li", class_="price-current")
```

so this for loop checks for prices, ratings, and the name of an item on a  website. it works. however, some items have no reviews, in which case it fails. how do i fix this? i was thinking of an if statement to check  if the containerElement (the actual container the item and all its information is in) has a rating, but im not exacatly sure how to do that

Comment: it depends on what you are looking for... how/where are the "reviews" defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
for containerElement in container:
    brandingElement = containerElement.find("div", class_="item-branding")
    titleElement=containerElement.find("a", class_="item-title")
    rating = brandingElement.find("i", {"class":"rating"})["aria-label"] if brandingElement.find("i", {"class":"rating"}) else ""
    priceElement = containerElement.find("li", class_="price-current")
```